# AWS IoT Greengrass Vs FreeRTOS

Tags: aws-iot, freertos, aws-iot-greengrass

I wonder when one will favor Greengrass over FreeRTOS? Any gotchas or empirical heads-up will be highly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Greengrass is designed for edge devices that are considered as heavier computer (at least in the edge), such as Raspberry Pi, IMX6/IMX8 devices and even PC's.

FreeRTOS (and AWS FreeRTOS) is designed for much leaner MCU (Microcontrollers), such as ESP32.

Comment: There's no mention of i.MX6/8 devices in the documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/setting-up.html#greengrass-v2-supported-platforms

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Greengrass and FreeRTOS are two totally different types of software.  [FreeRTOS](https://aws.amazon.com/freertos/) is an "operating system" that powers embedded MCU for sensors and smart lightbulbs, for examples. [Greengrass](https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass/) is AWS's IOT edge computing platform and it runs on  Linux.